# Trivial changes in NumPy-vectorized function's domain produce huge discrepancies. Why are the results so different?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wrote a custom "bump" function for some signal processing:

```
def bump(x):
    if x <= 0 or x >= 1:
        res = 0
    if x >= 0.1 and x <= 0.9:
        res = 1
    if 0 <= x and x < 0.1:
        res = 0.5*(np.cos(10*np.pi*(x-0.1))+1)
    elif 0.9 < x and x <= 1:
        res = 0.5*(np.cos(10*np.pi*(x-0.9))+1)        
    return res

bump = np.vectorize(bump)
```

(As usual, I've imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt` and `numpy` as `np`.)

In verifying that the function is working as expected, I discovered that slightly changing the domain of this function, in the sense of using different start and endpoints for `np.linspace`, produce dramatically different graphs. I've included the behavior below, showing that it sometimes does exactly what I expect and other times is hugely different.

Am I misunderstanding the vectorization here? Should I be doing something else entirely? Examples follow.

Making a simple plot of this function works as expected.

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 10000)
plt.plot(t, bump(t))
```

[image]

Zooming into the last 10% of a translated version again gives the "zoomed-in" picture one expects.

```
ts = np.linspace(0.95, 1.05, 10000)
plt.plot(ts, bump((ts+0.05)/1.1))
```

[image]

Now, if I try to reveal just a bit more of the graph...

```
ts = np.linspace(0.9, 1.05, 10000)
plt.plot(ts, bump((ts+0.05)/1.1))
```

[image]

Trying other translations of `bump` produce similar strange behavior, where for some translations we get a smooth transition, other times we get step functions.

Comment: For efficiency, you should use `np.where` instead of `if` and `vectorize`.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! So this replaces vectorizing <code>bump</code> entirely?

Comment: If you use `where` in this function, you should not need to use `vectorize`.

Comment: One more question about vectorization: based on the question that this is marked as a duplicate of, it seems like the first graph (based on np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)) shouldn't give the smooth transition because the first element of t is 0.0. It also doesn't seem like the step function graph should work that way, since the first element of (t+0.05)/1.1 is about 0.863. What am I not getting here?

Comment: You wrote your conditions in a pretty weird way, and accidentally got them overlapping. The `res` value set by the first condition is overridden by the third condition.

Comment: As for the step function graph, 0.863 falls under the `res = 1` case.

Comment: Ah! I see now. I thought it was the datatype of the zeroth *input* that determines what vectorize does, rather than the output. Thanks!!

Comment: `np.vectorize` is **not** a speed tool. Read its docs carefully.  Note what it says about a trial calculation (and `otypes`).  It can be useful, but it is often naively misused.

Comment: If you returned `res=0.` or `1.0` (floats) you wouldn't see this behavior.  Or used `otypes`